# Visual Studio HTML Cursor-within-HTML-Element Syntax-highlighting color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to change grey highlight color in the screenshot below to something that will make the text a little more legible. Does anyone know what the "Display Item" name is that I need to change?

To get to the "theme editor" select ***Tools* => *Options* => *Environment* => *Fonts and Colors***. I can't find what to edit.

I've also looked through ***Tools* => *Options* => *Text Editor* => *HTML* => *Formatting*** to no avail.

[image]

In case you are wondering the theme is a slightly modified [Coding Instinct Theme](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/coding-instinct-theme)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try "Brace Matching (Rectangle)" (the background color).

Comment: I had a similar issue to David on `cshtml` pages and this pointed me in the right direction. The highlight of matching HTML tags with the VS2015 dark theme requires you to change the background colour of "Brace Matching".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

**Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors**

Display item:
 - Selected Text
 - Inactive Selected Text

Comment: Unfortunately those are set to blue and dark grey.